# Assigning directory name to a variable in cmd batch

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I want to retrieve a file name and assign it to a variable so I can use it further in the script.

```
set directoryName = dir Docum?nt*
echo %directoryName%
```

But once I execute the batch file all I get is this.

```
D:\ >a.bat
D:\ >set directoryName = dir Docum?nt*
D:\ >echo
ECHO is on.
```

How can I make sure that my variable has been assigned the value i.e. the directory name so I can start writing further script.

my `a.bat` contains:

```
set directoryName=dir Docum?nt*
echo %directoryName%
```

**After removing spaces:**

```
D:\Workspace>set directoryName=dir Docum?nt*

D:\Workspace>echo dir Docum?nt*
dir Docum?nt*
```

I guess, the vairbale has been assigned the whole value along with the command keyword instead of the results. I expect the output to be the directory name i.e. `Documentation`

Comment: Easy... use `set directoryName=dir Docum?nt*` just like that. You have white space so just remove it... Let me know if this helps and I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have white space before and after the equal sign of the setting of the variable, just remove it and use the method below for example.

```
@ECHO ON

set directoryName=dir Docum?nt*
echo %directoryName%
```

**Wrong**

- `set directoryName = dir Docum?nt*`

**Correct**

- `set directoryName=dir Docum?nt*`
  [image]

**Implicit FOR Loop**

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /AD "Docum?nt*"') DO SET directoryName=%%~F
```

**Recursive FOR Loop**

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /AD /S "Docum?nt*"') DO SET directoryName=%%~F
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: Thankyou, i still have issues with output, please check my updated question.

Comment: @Maven I just updated my answer since you updated the question with a way to put that in a loop for your DIR command and the wildcards to get the expected result(s). You may need to add IF logic to filter it down to something explicit folder name wise or else it'll get all matches.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is to set the directory name which matches `Docum?nt*`, then what you need is:

```
for /d %%d in (Docum?nt*) do set directoryName="%%d"
```

If more than one directory matches the mask, then you will get only one of the matches. If you need the variable to hold a list of the matching directories, then you will need to use `for /f`.

Comment: I tried this and got `%%d was unexpected at this time`

Answer (score 3):

No spaces.

If you have to use space in names, put them under this format:

```
set directoryName = "dir Docum?nt*"
```

It's either **""** or **no spaces**.

Comment: Thankyou, i still have issues with output, please check my updated question.

Comment: @Maven: Overmind meant spaces in the provided variable name. Your updated code does not match the code suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### I expect the output to be the directory name i.e. `Documentation`

You won't get `Documentation` as an output unless you **run** the command you have stored in the variable.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set directoryName=dir Docum?nt*
rem run command
cmd /c %directoryName%
pause 
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> test
dir Docum?nt*
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

09/03/2017  17:10    <DIR>          Documentation
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  1,701,065,842,688 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.